# Xamarin accessing Button.Clicked from one page to another

Tags: c#, xamarin, event-handling

I'm have a few Carousel pages set up, and on each page I have Buttons `CurrentView` and `DefaultView` which instantiate images or labels. I want the to make the buttons global, if you hit `currentView` then the `currentView` shows is clicked on all pages.

Any tips or advice to get in the right direction is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like storing that the button was clicked in a shared preference

```
private readonly ISharedPreferences _prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
```

Then maybe in the OnResume of the Activity check if the button was clicked

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        _prefs.GetBoolean("clicked", false);
   }
```

When ever you click or unclick the button, set the preference

```
private void OnCLick(object sender, EventArgs e){

 ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = _prefs.Edit();
        editor.PutBoolean("FirstRun", false);
        editor.Apply();
}
```

This is only sample code, i haven't tested this in an app. I use something similar for to check if the user has dismissed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static Enumerable (list, array, etc.) of button and then add your buttons to it then use:

```
foreach(Buttton btn in theList)
    btn.CallOnClick();
```

in your click handlers of each button.